# Scrape code from website with python and beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

My project is about scraping 5 shopping websites. I found useful data from StackOverflow and from youtube. But I am stuck on one website. 
One div class used style display, none and hidden visibility after that all div classes are hidden. I tried to use ajax, google chrome extension for javascript, and applied different methods which I applied on the other 4 but this website is a bit hard for me. If someone helps me to read those tags so that I can scrape data from a website that would be beneficial. 
Website URL is : [Website](https://homeshopping.pk/search.php?q=dell)

currently, I am using simple code for parse. here is the code which I used.

```
 y = requests.get(url)

 soup = BeautifulSoup(y.text, "html.parser")
 products = soup.find('div', class_='container min-w1170')
 products = products.find('div', class_='row mgt25')

 print(products)

 products = products.find_all("div", class_="findify-components-common--grid__column findify-components-common--grid__column-6")
 print(products)
```

until first print, all div classes are working but after that, I am unable to find data from next div classes.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: @JackFleeting product name, price, image URL, product URL.

Comment: That info is dynamically loaded using javascript. Search around for info on using Selenium.

Comment: I already tried selenium but it was not working on this website, on another website I used selenium web driver with chrome and it works. I am sure I am missing one or two things but unable to identify it. I am trying since 2 days. but now sure why its not working with ajax or selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will get you everything you want. The trick to working with beautifulsoup is to analyze the html carefully and look for patterns in elements. The error in your code was probably using the wrong attribute values.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from socket import socket

url = 'https://homeshopping.pk/search.php?q=dell'
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,features='html.parser')

products = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'findify-components--cards--product innerp product-box'})  # the div for each product tile
for product in products:
    name = (product.find('span',{'class':'findify-components--text findify-components--cards--product__title'})).get_text()
    price = (product.find('span',{'class':'price findify-components--cards--product--price__price'})).get_text()
    img_src = product.find('img')
    all_urls = product.find_all('a')
    product_url = all_urls[1]   # it will always be the second one
    product_url_only = product_url['href']
```